# mhchem - make font bold in \ce{} environment

Tags: bold, mhchem

How can the output of the `\ce{}` macro of `mhchem`  be typeset as **bold**?

Comment: Add a MWE, please with an image (optional).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glancing at the manual, you can set this globally by adding

```
\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\bfseries,mathfontcommand=\mathbf}
```

to the preamble.

For single instances in text mode, you can use `\textbf{\ce{..}}`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{H2O} %not bold

\textbf{\ce{H2O}} % bold

\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\bfseries,mathfontcommand=\mathbf}

\ce{H2O} %bold

$\ce{H2O}$ %bold
\end{document}
```

[image]